# :hover на iOS vs Android

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $page = $('html, body');
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
        $page.animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
  margin-top: 2200px;
}

.show {
  display: none;
  background: aquamarine;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover ~ .show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#box">Scroll BOX!</a>
<div class="show">
  Text text text yo
 </div>
 
<div id="box">
  <h2> Hi Scroll! </h2>
</div>
```

Что меня волнует: на iOS(iPhone) при нажатии на ссылку срабатывает :hover, при втором нажатии происходит scroll. Всё круто.

На Android же при нажати срабатывает :hover и скролл сразу. Как сделать чтобы на Android было такое же поведение? Или хотя бы какой-то компромисс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Всё круто

**IMHO**: не круто. это  неверное поведение.

### как сделать по вашему ? - средствами JS

1. определить мобильный браузер или десктопный, если мобильный
2. по первому клику показывать. по второму - переходить

### как сделать правильно ?

в приведённом ниже коде, не используется ни одной библиотеки,
а `JavaScript` используется исключительно для формирования `HTML`

```js
let html = (a, ...b) => String.raw(a, ...b);
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getStyle());
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let data = [
        ['a', 'b', '#box'],
        ['a', 'b', '#box'],
        ['a', 'b', '#box'],
    ];
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html `
        <header>${getNav(data)}</header>
        <section>
            <div id="box">
                <h2> Hi Scroll! </h2>
            </div>
        </section>
    `);
});
function getNav(arr) {
    let line = (arr) => html `
        <li>
            <ul>
                ${arr[2] ? html `
                <a href="${arr[2]}">
                    <li>${arr[1]}</li>
                </a>
                ` : null}
            </ul>
            ${arr[0]}
        </li>
        `;
    return html `
    <nav>
        <ul>
            ${arr.map(line).join('')}
        </ul>
    </nav>
    `;
}
function getStyle() {
    return html `<style>
        #box {
            margin-top: 2200px;
        }
        ul {
            margin: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере IE и Opera */
            padding: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере Firefox, Safari, Chrome */
            display: inline-block;
            width: 70px;
        }
        li {
            list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры */
            border-bottom: solid 1px;
        }
        ul li:hover {
            background-color: gray;
        }
        /* , */
        ul li ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 78px;
        }
        ul li ul li {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        ul li:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    `;
}
```

Comment: мне как джуну трудно понять что тут написано (

Comment: правая кнопка по менюшке(а,а,а) -> посмотреть код . там будет только `html` внутри `iframe`. копируй себе в  `index.html` и изучай.

Comment: если есть желание понять что тут написано - рекомендую установить `VSCode` + плагин `lit-html`(подсвечивает `html` внутри `js`)